# Finding 1996'th term for given recurrence relation

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

I've been given the sequence $a_n$ defined by the recursion relation:  $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n}{1+na_n}\qquad a_1=1$$

and have been tasked to find $a_{1996}$.  How would I go about that?

I have a basic knowledge about recursions.

I don't know how to isolate $a_n$ since it appears twice in the equation.

Anybody have a clue how to proceed?

Comment: $$\frac1{a_{n+1}}=\frac1{a_n}+n$$

Comment: $b_{n+1}=b_n + n$

Comment: But how can we remove a(n+1) to find 1996'th term?

Comment: i computed the first few terms. they are:$1, \frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 1 7, \frac1{11}, \ldots, \frac 2{n^2 + n+2}, \ldots$

Answer (score 3):

$$
\frac1{a_{n+1}}=\frac1{a_n}+n
$$

let $b_n = \frac1{a_n}$
$$
b_{n+1}=b_n + n
$$
Using recursion, 
$$
b_1 = 1\\
b_2 = 1+1\\
b_3 = 1+1+2\\
\vdots\\
b_n = 1+\sum_{n=0}^{n-1} n = 1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
Then, 
$$
a_n = \frac{2}{2+n(n-1)}
$$